# Substitution with sed + bash function

Tags: bash, sed, substitution

my question seems to be general, but i can't find any answers.

In sed command, how can you replace the substitution pattern by a value returned by a simple bash function.

For instance, I created the following function :

```
function parseDates(){
    #Some process here with $1 (the pattern found)
    return "dateParsed;
}
```

and the folowing sed command :

```
myCatFile=`sed -e "s/[0-3][0-9]\/[0-1][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]/& parseDates &\}/p" myfile`
```

I found that the caracter '&' represents the current pattern found, i'd like it to be passed to my bash function and the whole pattern to be substituted by the pattern found +dateParsed.

Does anybody have an idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can glue together a sed-command by ending a single-quoted section, and reopening it again.

```
sed -n 's|[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]|& '$(parseDates)' &|p' datefile
```

However, in contrast to other examples, a function in bash can't return strings, only put them out:

```
function parseDates(){
    # Some process here with $1 (the pattern found)
    echo dateParsed
}
```

Comment: I still have a problem with this solution. The bash function is called. But the argument & seems not to be correctly copied In the function because i can't use $1 In reference to &.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, but above solution is for a function which doesn't take arguments only, and is evaluated before the sed command. The other possibility is, to call it later `$(script $(sed 'sedcmd' file))`

Answer (score 4):

you can use the "e" option in sed command like this:

```
cat t.sh

myecho() {
        echo ">>hello,$1<<"
}
export -f myecho
sed -e "s/.*/myecho &/e" <<END
ni
END
```

you can see the result without "e":

```
cat t.sh

myecho() {
        echo ">>hello,$1<<"
}
export -f myecho
sed -e "s/.*/myecho &/" <<END
ni
END
```

Comment: the option 'e' is not recognized. Also i tried to export my function via export -f parseDate, which is not working. this example doesn't work for me.

Comment: I had to toss change it to `$(myecho)`

Comment: The `/e` fag is a GNU `sed` extension, and not portable. If your target audience is Linux, you can _probably_ expect them to have GNU `sed` (somewhat also depending on the distro).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to know if there's a way to do this too. However, for this particular problem you don't need it. If you surround the different components of the date with `()`s, you can back reference them with `\1` `\2` etc and reformat however you want.

For instance, let's reverse 03/04/1973:

```
echo 03/04/1973 | sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\/\([0-9][0-9]\)\/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g'
```

Comment: If you want to tidy up the /s in your command, sed is able to accept characters other than / for the substitution construct (s///), e.g. the following should be equivalent to your example:  
    `echo 03/04/1973 | sed -e 's#\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)#\3/\2/\1#g'`

Comment: @drysdam You helped me big time with \1 and \2 thing. Cheers. +1 vote

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Glenn Jackman.
If you want to use bash function in sed, something like this :

```
sed -rn 's/^([[:digit:].]+)/`date -d @&`/p' file |
while read -r line; do
    eval echo "$line"
done
```

My file here begins with a unix timestamp (e.g. 1362407133.936).

Answer (score 1):

Bash function inside sed (maybe for other purposes):

```
multi_stdin(){ #Makes function accepet variable or stdin (via pipe)
    [[ -n "$1" ]] && echo "$*" || cat -
}

sans_accent(){ 
    multi_stdin "$@" | sed '
        y/àáâãäåèéêëìíîïòóôõöùúûü/aaaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuu/
        y/ÀÁÂÃÄÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜ/AAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUU/
        y/çÇñÑß¢Ðð£Øø§µÝý¥¹²³ªº/cCnNBcDdLOoSuYyY123ao/
    '
}

eval $(echo "Rogério Madureira" | sed -n 's#.*#echo & | sans_accent#p')
```

or

```
eval $(echo "Rogério Madureira" | sed -n 's#.*#sans_accent &#p')

Rogerio
```

And if you need to keep the output into a variable:

```
VAR=$( eval $(echo "Rogério Madureira" | sed -n 's#.*#echo & | desacentua#p') )
echo "$VAR"
```

Answer (score 0):

do it step by step. (also you could use an alternate delimiter , such as "|" instead of "/"

```
function parseDates(){
    #Some process here with $1 (the pattern found)
    return "dateParsed;
}

value=$(parseDates)
sed -n "s|[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]|& $value &|p" myfile
```

Note the use of double quotes instead of single quotes, so that $value can be interpolated

Comment: I believe that what is requested is for the matched pattern to be passed as an argument to the bash function.

Comment: dateParsed needs no opening `"` or a closing one, and instead of "return", which can only return an int, an echo or printf.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's#[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]#& $(parseDates &)#' myfile |
while read -r line; do
    eval echo "$line"
done
```