# Substitute Yaml values with yq by new value as output of bash function which accept current value as input

Tags: yaml, substitution, yq

#### Overview

- Something like [Substitution with sed + bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777170/substitution-with-sed-bash-function)
  But using `yq`
- **yq** of **kislyuk** not other **yq** projects https://github.com/kislyuk/yq (`pip install yq`)

#### Details

I have this bash function :

```sh
function replace_image_repo() {
  echo "nexus.local/${1}"
}
```

On the other side, i have a YAML file:

```yaml
# pod.yaml
kind: Pod
# ...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web
      image: nginx
    - name: logger
      image: abdennour/logger
```

I am able to replace all value occurences of `.image` key by a static value:

```sh
yq -y '(.. | .image?) |= "mynewimage"' pod.yaml
```

And the result is as expected:

```yaml
# pod.yaml
kind: Pod
# ...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web
      image: mynewimage # <-- Replacement done successfully
    - name: logger
      image: mynewimage # <-- Replacement done successfully
```

However, I want to leverage the bash function above `replace_image_repo` and call it to **calculate the new value for each occurrence based on the current value** :

- for example, `nginx` must be replaced by the output of `$(replace_image_repo nginx)` which should be `nexus.local/nginx`.
- Is it possible to match the current value ?
- If so , is it possible a call the Bash function "yq -y '.... $(HERE)'" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do much better than that. Since https://github.com/kislyuk/yq makes use of the prowess of `jq` underneath, you can use the latter's `--arg` fields to pass in the values that you want to replace. For e.g. your case could be customized to pass the old and the new replacement strings to be passed.

Also the `jq` filter expression `(.. | .image?) |= "mynewimage"` is not the best of approaches, as `..` uses a [recursive descent parsing](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..), you might end up `null` values in your modified result. The right approach would be to modify the filter to match the exact object containing the string and replace with the target value.

Recommend dropping the non-standard keyword `function` from shell functions esp. `bash`

```
replace_image_repo() {
  printf '%s' "nexus.local/${1}"
}
```

and use `yq` as

```
yq -y --arg old "nginx" \
      --arg new "$(replace_image_repo "nginx")" \
      '.spec.containers |= map( select(.image == $old).image = $new )' yaml
```

Or if your requirement is to apply the substitution to all `.image` fields under containers, you can do below without using a shell function.

```
yq -y '.spec.containers |= map(.image = "nexus.local/\(.image)")' yaml
```

You can customize it further by passing the prefix string as an argument

```
yq -y --arg prefix "nexus.local/" '.spec.containers |= map(.image = ($prefix + "\(.image)") )' yaml
```

---

Considering your argument about having to use a much complex shell function, you can do the following approach. The two parse on the YAML first to get the new image names based on the shell function (complex, now abstracted) and then later re-use the results to replace the image names on the original file back.

This is because `jq` doesn't allow executing arbitrary shell functions in its expression context yet.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

replace_image_repo() {
  printf '%s' "nexus.local/${1}"
}


convert_to_array() {
    local results=()
    while IFS= read -r image; do
        results+=( \"$(replace_image_repo "$image")\" )
    done < <(yq -r '.spec.containers[].image' yaml)
    local IFS=","
    printf '[%s]' "${results[*]}"
}


yq -y --argjson images "$(convert_to_array)" \
    'reduce range(0; $images | length) as $i (.;
       .spec.containers[$i].image = $images[$i])' yaml
```

Comment: Thank you @Inian . However, the bash function `replace_image_repo` is too complicated and i don't have time to convert it to python. I put the function definition like this just to get perspective about the concern.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI: See update, I've modified answer to make sure, your shell function is called on each image name and then the original YAML is updated back with the updated names